# Preventing blocking when using cursor over stored proc in transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, database-cursor

I'm trying to work out how I can prevent blocking while running my code. There are a few things I could swap out, and I'm not sure which would be best. I'm including below some fake code to illustrate my current layout, please look past any syntax errors

```sql
SELECT ID
INTO #ID
FROM Table

DECLARE @TargetID int = 0

BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE ID_Cursor FOR
    SELECT ID
    FROM TABLE

    OPEN ID_Cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM ID_Cursor
    INTO @TargetID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC usp_ChangeID
        @ID = @TargetID
        @NewValue = 100

        FETCH NEXT FROM ID_Cursor INTO @TargetID
    END

    CLOSE ID_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE ID_Cursor

IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Value = 100) = 10000)
   COMMIT TRAN
ELSE
   ROLLBACK TRAN
```

The problem I'm encountering is that the usp_ChangeID in my code updates about 15 tables each run and other spids that want to work with any of those tables are needing to wait until the entire process is done running. The stored proc itself runs in about a second, but I need to run it repeatedly. I'm thinking that these locks are because of the transaction rather than the cursor itself, though I'm not 100% sure. Ideally, my code would finish one run of the stored proc, let other users through to the tables, then run again once that other operation is complete. The rows I'm working with each time shouldn't be frequently used so a row lock would be perfect, but the blocking I'm seeing implies that isn't happening.

This is running on production data so I want to leave as little impact as possible while this runs. Performance hits are fine if it means less blocking. I don't want to break this into chunks because I generally want this to only be saved if every record is updated as expected and rolled back in any other case. I can't modify the proc, go around the proc, or do this without a cursor involved either. I'm leaning towards breaking my initial large select into smaller chunks, but I'd rather not have to change parts manually.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could move your transaction to be inside the cursor loop. That way it runs a separate transaction each trip. Or even better, rewrite your logic so you don't need a cursor at all.

Comment: If I were to move the transaction inside the cursor, I wouldn't really have a good reason to use a transaction in the first place. The goal of the transaction is to only commit if I get the results I'm expected after the cursor is done, so it can only meaningfully exist outside of the cursor loop. Of course I'd love to not use a cursor if I could, but that's the only way I can repeatedly fire this proc that only accepts one ID at a time.

Comment: Well if you can't move the transaction inside the cursor you are going to have to wait. That is what happens when you change data in a transaction. The data becomes locked and other processes have to wait until the lock is released

Comment: Fair enough. That's about what I figured, but wanted to be sure before going the somewhat harder way around.

Comment: What concurrency model are you using?

Comment: I honestly have no idea what concurrency model it would be. It doesn't look like a memory or CPU wait if that's what you're wondering though. I can maybe find that info if it's particularly relevant?